# How to use crontab or to install?

Tags: cron

why this happen ? path error?
I installed crontab, but nothing changed.
path error then how to fix

```
crontab -e
'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: check `/usr/bin` and see if there is an executable named `crontab`. If it is there, then your `PATH` is messed up. Append the path to the env PATH, like `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/`

Comment: What OS are you using? How was crontab installed?

Comment: is crontab in .exe or .py?

Comment: windoqs10     from pip    and from Anacinda site

Answer (score 0):

Please check these steps in:

[https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/ubuntu-crontab/](https://crontab.guru/)

You can install it using:

```
apt-get install cron
```

Then to use it(to edit crontab file), you can go with:

```
crontab -e
```

or

```
sudo crontab -e
```

!**Make sure you use absoulte path in your code for any path definition/file path**

After file opened in your terminal, press "i" to enter INSERT mode. Then add your changes. e.g.

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/admin/my_py.py
```

After you typed your changes, press "ESC" then write "wq" after ":" means "write then quit" to alter the file. After this, you will see a message that changes will be applied.

The change we made will run that file at every hour past 5 minutes. (00:05 -> 01:05 -> 02:05 -> etc.)
For more information and clear understanding about these (* * * * *) marks, check this awesome site https://crontab.guru/

Comment: can not use apt-get   also it is not useful to use conda/pip install